# Internet Computer - Matoko print instruction not printing to terminal

Tags: internet-computer

I am new to internet computer. I wrote the following code on Visual Studio:

```
import Debug "mo:base/Debug";

    actor DBank {
        currentValue = 300;
        currentValue :=100;

        Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
    }
```

I typed, *dfx start*, to start the server and got the message

```
May 29 02:03:07.969 INFO Starting server. Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000/*
```

And then opened another terminal window and typed, *dfx deploy*. But the terminal with the server doesn't show the currentValue (of 100) as I expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show your value due to the fact that canister can not be deployed as there are errors in your code.

You need to first declare your variable `currentValue` as `mutable` and declare its type.

For example you can try with this:

```
import Debug "mo:base/Debug";

actor DBank {
    var currentValue : Int = 300;
    currentValue :=100;
    
    Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
    
    let hello : Text = "Hello world";
    Debug.print(debug_show(hello));

}
```

this should give you output:

```
[Canister rrkah-fqaaa-aaaaa-aaaaq-cai] +100
[Canister rrkah-fqaaa-aaaaa-aaaaq-cai] "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized variable properly

```
import Debug "mo:base/Debug";
actor Dbank{
  var currentValue = 300;
  currentValue := 100;
  Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
}
```